# Determine The driven distance of Specific Trasnporter Fleet in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I need to determine the distance that transporter fleet traveled from one nodeto other node
kindly see attached example that show transporter fleet travel from one point to another ,so I need to determine the driven distance from source to destination and from destination to source

[enter link description here](https://www.mediafire.com/file/zhxpbdyubxn198f/Modelpeds1.rar/file)

Comment: Check out Transport models, see Practical management Science by Winston & Albright.

Comment: you may want to share more details on this, what you already tried, when you need this, what the model setup looks like. Some tips: https://benjamin-schumann.squarespace.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow

Comment: Note: You cannot measure distance to a fleet, only to a specific transporter agent within the fleet ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can always call the `distanceTo(...)` method from any agent to any other point:
[image]

Or you use `getDistance(myHomeNode.getX(), myHomeNode.getY())` from your transporter agent, where `myHomeNode` is the home node itself.

Obviously, you need to adapt this code for your specific situation (since you did not share details on your model architecture and setup)

Comment: where i can put this code exactly and where the result can appear??

Comment: It depends, please improve your question to help with this

Comment: I Already Edit The Question As You Mention And Attach Example To Explain What I Need To Do

Comment: Any update?i need to know the distance driven by transporter in attached example

Comment: no time to check your model, sorry. Try to rephrase the question and add details as per my tips. The ideal question allows an answer in 1 word. The second-best question can be answered in 1 sentence. The worst questions require a full study of your model and try to decipher what you try to achieve... The latter are unlikely to be answered here. Treat us as very busy colleagues that are happy to help. But your goal must always be to make *our* lives easy, not yours :) See https://benjamin-schumann.squarespace.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow